# fixing text in webpage

Tags: html

i want that my text eg. "registration" which is the topmost text and is a heading,to  remain fixed on the screen and then when i scroll "registration" should remain intact at the top of the screen and all other text should go beneath it while scrolling. how can i do this???? please reply soon... Thanks to all for your time in advance.

Comment: the [php5] tag wasn't really appropriate to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure do I understand correctly what you are trying to achive, but i'll give it a shot. If you are trying to create fixed position header you can use the same technique like in fixed footer. You can find more info in this [fixed footer documentation](http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/footer)

And here goes the example code:

```
<!-- IE in quirks mode -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<title>Fixed footer</title>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 <length> 0;
 }
 div#footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:<length>;
 }
 @media screen{
  body>div#footer{
   position: fixed;
  }
 }
 * html body{
  overflow:hidden;
 } 
 * html div#content{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
 }
</style>
<div id="footer"> footer </div>
<div id="content"> content </div>
```

Comment: oh!! ya same logic as that of fixing footer can bi implemented for header too.. thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position: fixed;` in CSS. It's recognized by pretty much every browser, except for IE6... but you shouldn't try to make stuff work there anyway.

```
.stayOnTop
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; /* to place it on top */
  left: 0; /* to place it in the left corner, that'd be the most logical place; although this obviously isn't necessary, you could want to put it in the right corner or somewhere else and whatever /longcomment */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want probably want to set the css attribute [position to fixed](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html) for this. Of course this behaviour is somewhat commonly seen with most browsers on most systems simply with the  tag!

Answer (score 1):

You should set your element's position property to "fixed" in your css.

```
#registration_element
{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
}
```

[this link should help](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: yup. i used that but by that the underlying text is not going beneath "registration" but its overlaping it while scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Use style position:fixed.

Here comes the example.

```
<style>
#idOfDiv {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>
<div id="idOfDiv"> TEST </div>
```

Comment: yup. i used that but by that the underlying text is not going beneath "registration" but its overlaping it while scrolling

Comment: @ican: sounds like you want to set a background too then.

Comment: nop.just i want other text shouldnt overlap "registration". i hav seen this working in many websites.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You can do that by padding other elements as appropriate then.

Comment: a piece of text eg "registration" should remain intact at top of page and when i do scroll only text beneath them should scroll and not text "registration".

Comment: yup. that already i had implemented. but i think Mareks logic gona help me. it accomplishes task as i want. thanks all.